# Hibernate: How do I rewrite this criteria to HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

I want to write HQL, where I find out if Company has Persons(employees) with some of given names. I've managed to do that with criteria:

```
public List<Person> namesInCompany(Company company, Session session,
            String... names) {
        return session.createCriteria(Person.class)
                .add(Restrictions.in("name", names))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("company", company))
                .list();
    }
```

Now, I'd like same for HQL. I am using named queries, but I am having trouble how to pass array or list of strings (or anything) as parameter for named query. Here's my attempt, that doesn't work atm.

```
<query name="namesInCompany">
            <query-param name="company" type="sk.xorty.task.Company"/>
            <query-param name="names" type="java.util.List"/>
            <![CDATA[
            from Person p
                where p.company = :company
                and p.name in (:names)
            ]]>
        </query>
```

I'm getting ClassCastException

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.StringTypeDescriptor.unwrap(StringTypeDescriptor.java:40)
```

That is normal, because I specified wrong type for query-param names. I don't know what to put there :/

Test case for better understanding of this service:

```
assertTrue (2 == service.namesInCompany(someCompany, session, "jon", "josh").size());
```

That means, that either "jon" or "josh" work at someCompany.

Thanks for help

**EDIT**

JB Nizet proposed code for service.namesInCompany. Here it is:

```
public List<Person> namesInCompany(Company company, Session session, 
            String... names) {
        Query namesInCompany = session.getNamedQuery(
                "sk.xorty.task.Person.namesInCompany");
        namesInCompany.setParameter("company", company);
        namesInCompany.setParameter("names", names);
        return namesInCompany.list();
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code of service.namesInCompany

Comment: @JB Nizet Done, please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You declare the parameter as `java.util.List`, but you pass an array of Strings (a varargs argument is in fact an array)
2. You must use `setParameterList`, and not `setParameter`, to pass a collection of values.